# Dual external monitors on laptop with two video outputs

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I've got an Asus N82Jv laptop with a nVidia GT 335M video card. This card has two outputs, a VGA and an HDMI. I'd like to know if a can use both of them (I mean at the same time) to use two external monitors without using the integrated LCD screen.

My video card support (according to the official specifications) multi monitor, but it does not mean I can use both of the video outputs at the same time without using the laptop screen.

I'm a bit confused and I wouldn't buy two monitors without being sure of what I can do. So, any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Please move to Superuser.com

Comment: Does it have the option of a docking station? I have an Dell laptop, that is able to drive 2 external monitors through a docking station. This automatically turns off the Laptops main monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. The 335M supports multiple simultaneous displays. I have the similarly specced N61JV-X2 and am currently using both the display outs.

Comment: is the integrated monitor automatically turned off when using the external monitors or can you use it as a third screen?

Comment: Third screen, that's the beauty of it :)

Comment: Woo! It's more than I expected ^^

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to set up the two external monitors to work with the integrated monitor, but I cannot make it works. The three screens are detected but only two are usable at the same time. How did you configure your display?