# Extended display over three monitors, on lenovo G580

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors

I have a laptop with a HDMI and a D-sub (VGA) output. I have two external monitors, and my laptop detects all three monitors (including its own), but can extend the desktop to only 2 of them (any two).

I want to use all three monitors, including my built-in laptop monitor, as an extended desktop.

I know, it's possible with a USB display adapter, but I found some source without mentioning any USB device with no tutorial for the solution. like this one:
[Dual external monitors on laptop with two video outputs](https://superuser.com/questions/383280/dual-external-monitors-on-laptop-with-two-video-outputs)

May using Windows 8.1 instead of 7 could help me?

How can I achieve this? Any help appreciated, but please note that I try to avoid to use USB devices.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** I Have a Lenovo G580, with a NVIDIA GeForce GT 630M graphic card, and a built-in Intel HD graphic card.

CPU #1 Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU B960 @ 2.20GHz, 2195 MHz

CPU #0 Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU B960 @ 2.20GHz, 2195 MHz

Comment: I think the two external connectors is one or the other. Try contacting your laptop manufacturer or read the technical specification for your device. If you could provide the laptop make and model then that may help...

Comment: Unless the GPU has enough outputs to support running all these displays, you’re out of luck. So please do include more details on your hardware. Software is pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: Can you post the model of the built in Intel HD graphics card? Also the CPU type (which generation?) It will help in identifying your exact model. Also, you say "any two"... does that mean that you can extend the monitor over the two external monitors at the same time? What happens to the built-in laptop monitor when you do this?

Answer (score 3):

Pending your chipset and processor, to correctly pin down your model, it seems that you can not. From [Lenovo G580 - dual monitors support](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-B-and-G-Series-Notebooks/Lenovo-G580-dual-monitors-support/td-p/1212770)

> I have checked the Technical Specifications and supported Hardware of
>   G580 Laptop and I’m sorry to inform you that the Dual monitor option
>   is not supported in this model.

From [G580 three screen support](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-B-and-G-Series-Notebooks/G580-three-screen-support/td-p/1106939)

> The Lenovo G580 runs on the  [Intel® H76 Express Chipset](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/chipsets/mainstream-chipsets/h61-express-chipset.html) as stated
>   on [this pdf](http://www.lenovo.com/psref/pdf/3book.pdf) data sheet which is capable of dual display only.

So, the answer appears to be no, the three monitor option is not available.

Although, there could be hope (again from [G580 three screen support](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-B-and-G-Series-Notebooks/G580-three-screen-support/td-p/1106939))

> Triple display maybe possible if you have a 3rd Gen CPU and Intel HD
>   Graphics 4000.

You could wade through these questions on an Intel Graphics Drivers [Configuration 3-Display FAQ](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-033714.htm). Unfortunately, there is way too much info to summarize it here accurately/concisely.

Comment: CPU #1 Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU B960 @ 2.20GHz, 2195 MHz, CPU #0 the same, does this information that we needed?

Comment: @TamásJuhász - Thanks. From that info, I don't think your laptop can do what you want to do. Although, it would still be good to also know which _chipset_ your laptop is using. BTW, it is best if you put this extra information in your original question rather than in a comment. You should also have a read of the [Tour](http://superuser.com/tour). :-)

Comment: Sorry, but now it's clear for me, I'm a noob in the topic of hardwares. I checked my laptop on the official Lenovo site, and now I'm totally confused about it... How can I check the exact infos about my CPU and chipset?

Comment: @TamásJuhász [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) can give you all the relevant information.

Comment: @TamásJuhász - don't forget to put the new info in your original question, and not as a comment. I have updated your question with the CPU info that you provided yesterday. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn off laptop display to enforce TV output to DVI + HDMI. I have Lenovo B580 with Intel Graphics 4000, which is very similar to G580 and it works well. Laptop will only display TWO display devices at the same time which ever combination (laptop + HDMI, laptop + VGA or VGA + HDMI) cannot display all three devices (laptop + HDMI + VGA).

In BIOS I switched graphics from Switchable to Integrated, though I am not sure if this helped.

Then on desktop (Win7 x64) I clicked (right mouse) and chose Intel Graphics Options -> Output to extended displays -> and selected combination "monitor + digital TV" (not e.g. "laptop + monitor"). My HDMI monitor was detected like digital TV, not sure why :-)

Still better to display on 2 widescreen monitors than on laptop + 1 monitor.

On boot laptop will first use standard laptop display (though also configurable in BIOS) and once Win7 started, it will turn off laptop display and switch to both monitors.